# Compile v8 for arm with custom cross-compiler on Windows

Tags: windows, embedded, arm, cross-compiling, v8

I want to compile a static v8 build to use on an embedded device.

The company that creates the device has given us a cross-compiler based on cygwin (the device uses a Linux-based OS), so that we can write and compile code on the windows platform, before transfering it to the device.

All tutorials I have seen for compiling V8 compiles on an arm system (like scratchbox) unless they are targeting the arm simulator. Would it be technically possible to just compile V8 as if I was compiling it for windows, only using the custom cygwin compiler that we ourselves use for compiling?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The longer answer is, what is the question?

Comment: Haha. The ting is V8 comes with GYP which is supposed to make a localized build-project (probably using Visual Studio stuff, hopefully using makefiles) to make it more easy for me to build the project. How can I make it compile using our custom cygwin-based arm-elf-gcc compiler, and will it work with the pre-build stuff gyp does?

Comment: What is "V8"? A bit engine!?  You might get a better answer or at least more views if you were more specific.

Comment: V8 is google chromes javascript JIT. I added a tag to make that clear

Comment: Is the provided cross-compiler a port of GCC that's hosted on Cygwin and targets  your ARM device?

Comment: [this](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP) suggests you just need to say `make arm.release`

Comment: @BenVoigt it says the arm simulator is the target, I don't know if this makes any difference. Problem is that GYP generates a Visual Studio project, although I've figured out how to make it generate a makefile project now. I still don't know if these makefiles will actually work on the arm device though. I'll post an answer when I've got a tested build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperantly, the provided cygwin compiler really was custom tailored for our devices. They even removed the math.h library, and added custom malloc/free as well as io functions. After a lot of effort, I managed to get a modified version of Lua to run on our platform, and I guess that's as good as it gets. Lua wins!